# Using multiple materials with THREE.CylinderGeometry - create a wheel from cylinder

Tags: three.js

I want to create a wheel from cylinder (because importing 3D models makes it slower). But I cannot use multiple materials with cylinder geometry. It uses only the first material in an array.

```
    var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(this.diameterWheel/2,this.diameterWheel/2,this.lastikGenisligi, 20, 4);

    var materialArray = [];
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000 }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '../textures/wheel.png' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000FF }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 }));

    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

What I want to create is a wheel which will have wheel.png wheel image on upper and bottom sides and black coverage on between them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each face on the cylinder and tell which of the array materials the face uses.

```
geometry.faces[a].materialIndex = b;
```

Where a is the face index. You need to figure out yourself which face is which to choose the correct material through some system, ie. faces 0-10 with one color, etc. This depends on the cylindergeometry parameters. And b is the material index.